# php file automatically changed to php.suspected

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, malware

I've running website  on a Linux server. This server runs a lot of website, most of them CMS, mainly WordPress.

And sometimes something renames my files from wp-db.php to wp-db.php.suspected for example.

And my site are goes down. 
Has anyone seen such thing before or has an idea what can causes it?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: these files sometimes suspected by your hosting provider, or wordfence plugin also it could be to trick you to ignore the files

Comment: ok Thanks @AbdulRafay

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835796/php-file-automatically-renamed-to-php-suspected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php file automatically renamed to php.suspected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835796/php-file-automatically-renamed-to-php-suspected)

Answer (score 0):

these files sometimes suspected by your hosting provider, or wordfence plugin also it could be to trick you to ignore the files

Comment: my site is goes down so how i install wordfence plugin?